# Howto convert a JSON nested dictionary to a JSON nested array in angular js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dictionary, nested

I want to create a form that would pop field values from existing JSON.
I have nested JSON with has dictionary, but I want them in arrays.

How can I write a recursive function to get the keys of the dictionary into a nested array?

This is my JSON code:

```
{
  "name": "Hello",
  "colors": {
  "primary": [
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255
  ],
  "secondary": [
      255,
      255,
      255,
      255
  ]
},
"dimensions": {
  "9:16": {
    "box": {
      "sr_no": 1,
      "computer": {
        "asset_1": {
          "type": "video",
          "out": {
            "layer": {
              "opac": 1,
              "effect": "None",
              "details": {
                "color": "tertiary",
                    "type": "noidea"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And what are expected results? Please note that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: are you talking about field name 'dimensions'?

Comment: @kchomski I am using angular, so ngFor does not support dictionary. Now, if I use pipe to get keyValuePair, it creates the view and add the field values, but if I add new dictionary in JSON, it does not add View.
This is because, ngFor is looping on array returned by Pipe and not on original JSON. So it does not update view or add HTML dynamically.

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar
Yeah, Dimensions has many options. I have just mentioned "16:9". Actual JSON is very long

Comment: @Sara I have posted answer

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar, it works! Thanks alot!

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer so that it will be helpful for other user facing similar issue

Answer (score 1):

I have created a recursive function 'getAllDimentions' to convert nested object to object array.

```js
    var data = {
        "name": "Hello",
        "colors": {
            "primary": [
                255,
                255,
                255,
                255
            ],
            "secondary": [
                255,
                255,
                255,
                255
            ]
        },
        "dimensions": {
            "9:16": {
                "box": {
                    "sr_no": 1,
                    "computer": {
                        "asset_1": {
                            "type": "video",
                            "out": {
                                "layer": {
                                    "opac": 1,
                                    "effect": "None",
                                    "details": {
                                        "color": "tertiary",
                                        "type": "noidea"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    function getAllDimentions(object) {
        for (var item in object) {
            var itemValue = object[item];
            if (typeof (itemValue) == 'object')
                getAllDimentions(itemValue);
            else {
                result.push({});
                result[result.length - 1][item] = itemValue;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    var result = [];
    console.log(getAllDimentions(data.dimensions));
```

Comment: It is just giving child values. I want complete nested dictionary json to be nested array